# How to use Test-Path on a directory containing square brackets in the name

Tags: powershell

I have a series of directories that have been created with square brackets in their name.  For some inexplicable reason, the `Test-Path` command returns `$false` when I run it against these directories, but returns `$true` if I run the same command against a directory without square brackets in the name.

The directories look like this:

```
[s]4343224D
[s]50AF43AF
```

The command I am running is:

```
Test-Path [s]50AF43AF
```

I have also tried:

```
Test-Path `[s`]50AF43AF
```

But this also returns $false.

Does anyone know how one might get `Test-Path` to return true when there really is a directory of that name?

Comment: ```Test-Path ``[s``]50AF43AF``` or ```Test-Path '`[s`]50AF43AF'```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `-LiteralPath` parameter for this:

```
Test-Path -LiteralPath '[s]50AF43AF'
```

Which is probably a better option than adding backticks if you're processing more than one path:

```
'[s]4343224D','[s]50AF43AF' | ForEach-Object { Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ }
```

Comment: Thanks heaps - the "-LiteralPath" flag turned out to be the cleanest option since I wanted to put the name of the path into a variable and search for that, and with the backticks I kept having to use .Replace() methods to swap the [ and ] for`[ and `] respectively, which was a nuisance. By using the LiteralPath flag, I was able to just accept the string as-is and it worked.  Thanks heaps again :-)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
Test-Path '`[s`]50AF43AF'
```